# Swift: How can I change the border colors of an Eureka form cell?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

How can I change the border colors of an Eureka form cell? I managed to make background color of the password field transparent but want to do the same for the borders.

[image]

Here's my code for the cell:

```
<<< ButtonRow() { (row: ButtonRow) -> Void in
        row.title = "Forgot your password?"
    }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("resetPassword", sender: nil)
    }).cellSetup { cell, row in
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)

        // How can I get this to work?
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0).CGColor
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a white border color? You also have to set the border width for that to work

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the tableView separator style I think.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```